# Make sure a templated function does not take a certain if-else-branch for some types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function with an if-else-branch. The if-branch can be taken for all types, but the else-branch only makes sense for numerical types (double and int will be used).

Is there a way to check and warn (at runtime, probably) when the program goes into the else-branch for non-numerical types?

```
template <class T>
T SIMDNode<DIM>::getNodeValue(Coord pos){

    if(condition){
        // ok for all types
    }
    else{
        // ok only for numerical types (double and int)
        assert((T == double) || (T == int)); // looking for something like this

       if((T != double) && (T != int)) error(); // or this
    }
}
```

I did some reserarch, but the common methods are not working in my case:

- `static_assert` does not work, since the compiler would always reach it
  when constructing the function for a non-numerical type.
- `dynamic_cast` also doesn't work since double and int are not
  polymorphic types.

Comment: The answer is overloading.

Comment: `assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits):

```
assert(std::is_same<double, T>::value == double) || (std::is_same<int, T>::value));
```

or probably

```
assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value);
```

But overloading or specialization may be more appropriate:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
SIMDNode<DIM>::getNodeValue(Coord pos){
    // Code for numerical type
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
SIMDNode<DIM>::getNodeValue(Coord pos){
    // Code for non numerical type
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) for this:

```
assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>{});
```